# How to make compare with Menus

Tags: python, scripting

Here, I have to execute some part of coding through selecting options in Enum property.

Here is my code

```
class MAYA_OT_Regg(bpy.types.Operator):
 bl_idname = "maya.regging"
 bl_label = "Regging"
 bl_description = "Regging"

 def execute(self, ctx):
    return {'FINISHED'}

 def invoke(self, ctx, evt):
    return self.execute(ctx)

class MAYA_OT_Dynamic(bpy.types.Operator):
 bl_idname = "maya.dynamic"
 bl_label = "Dynamic"
 bl_description = "Dynamic"

 def execute(self, ctx):
    return {'FINISHED'}

 def invoke(self, ctx, evt):
    return self.execute(ctx)

class MENU_OT_SET(bpy.types.Menu):
 bl_label = "Menu Set"
 bl_description = "Menu set"
 def draw(self, ctx):
    ui = self.layout
    ui.operator("maya.regging")
    ui.operator("maya.dynamic")

class MAYA_OM_Panel_OP(bpy.types.Panel):
 bl_label       = "maya Tools"
 bl_space_type  = "VIEW_3D"
 bl_region_type = "TOOL_PROPS"

 def draw(self, ctx):
    ui = self.layout
    r = ui.row()
    r.menu("MENU_OT_SET", text="Menu set")
    # HERE I HAVE to COMPARE with that menu Regging and Dynamics
```

How to compare that Menus(Regging and Dynamics) If it's Dynamic,I have to execute some part of coding, else If it's Regging,I have to execute some part of coding.

I have searched out but none is matched with my code, so How It's possible?

Comment: Why not use an `if` statement?

Comment: if ctx.mode == 'OBJECT': like this I can compare but how to compare that one....?

Comment: Where's the `Enum` property?

Comment: sorry that is Menu now I had edited...

Answer (score 6):

If you need user-selectable options through drop-down menu, one alternative is to use [`EnumProperty`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty). For example, I use this property type to give some options to user:

```
widget_shape = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name = 'Shape',
    items = [('sphere', 'Sphere', '8x4 edges'),
             ('ring', 'Ring', '24 vertices'),
             ('square', 'Square', ''),
             ('triangle', 'Triangle', ''),
             ('bidirection', 'Bidirection', ''),
             # etc.
             ])
```

... that will be drawn by Blender as a drop-down menu:

[image: 1a]

Upon operator invocation, I could select the function to execute based on user selection in `self.widget_shape` (not exactly [how I did it](https://github.com/adhihargo/rigging_tools/blob/1fcf98cbdc663beca7ef15995fb37b26e78bbb37/rigging_tools.py#L579), but basically the same):

```
if self.widget_shape == 'sphere':
    self.create_sphere_widget()
elif self.widget_shape == 'ring':
    self.create_ring_widget()
# etc.
```

Comment: you can pass a callback to EnumProperty(..., update=the_callback_func) to perform code when the user clicks an entry.