# How to create a collapsible panel?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Is it possible to make collapsible panel like it is for object modifiers? I need something similar for my plugin. After choose menu item I want to create new panel with collapsible box, where can I change parameters for objects.

[image: screenshot]

I tried before to make panel with [bpy.types.UILayout.template_list](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=template_list#bpy.types.UILayout.template_list) but it was too hard to build from scratch for me. Documentation isn't very friendly, it's hard to know what can I use for these arguments (`active_dataptr`, `active_propname`).

Next months I'm working on my plugin, before that I need to make good UI for it.

Comment: Have you tried to check the Python code for the modifiers' UI?

Comment: Yes I tried but it's more complex and associated with different global variables. Here is a [part of modifier UI](http://pastebin.com/NBTdJUaV)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make compare with Menus](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5500/how-to-make-compare-with-menus)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's basically a camouflaged checkbox (boolean property) with changing icon:

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object

        box = layout.box()

        row = box.row()
        row.prop(obj, "expanded",
            icon="TRIA_DOWN" if obj.expanded else "TRIA_RIGHT",
            icon_only=True, emboss=False
        )
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)

        if obj.expanded:
            row = box.row()
            row.prop(obj, "name")

            row = box.row()
            row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

            row = box.row()
            row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Object.expanded = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=True)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    del bpy.types.Object.expanded


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: For anyone using Blender 2.8+ passing around : now you can also create a sub-panel (create another Panel and set its bl_parent_id property to the  bl_idname of the first one). Make sure you define draw method in the parent panel (even if empty) and it will render the child panel in a foldable way.

Comment: for anyone running into same issue with `obj.expanded` is specific to that object. if you want the panel expanded "globally" for every object you can use `bpy.types.Scene.expanded` when registering then use `context.scene.expanded` in the `draw` function