# create drop-down list in menu panel

Tags: python

I tried to create a menu panel for drawing the mesh, so I applied:

```
import bpy

class CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """A Custom Panel in the Viewport Toolbar"""
    bl_label = "Generate"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Generate objects:")

        split = layout.split()
        col = split.column(align=True)

        layout.label(text="Primitives:")
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_plane_add", text="Plane", icon='MESH_PLANE')
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", icon='MESH_CUBE', text="Cube")
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_circle_add", icon='MESH_CIRCLE', text="Circle")
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add", icon='MESH_UVSPHERE', text="UV Sphere")                
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add", text="Ico Sphere", icon='MESH_ICOSPHERE')
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cylinder_add", text="Cylinder", icon='MESH_CYLINDER')
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cone_add", text="Cone", icon='MESH_CONE')
        layout.operator("mesh.primitive_torus_add", text="Torus", icon='MESH_TORUS')


        #
        col.operator("mesh.primitive_plane_add", text="Plane"), 
        col.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="Cube")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

but when I try to ecris as a drop-down list, like this:
[How to make compare with Menus](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5500/how-to-make-compare-with-menus/5501#5501)
I haven't succeeded, someone help me how writing in menu panel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**the easy way by reusing existing UI code**

[image]

code:

```
import bpy

class CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """A Custom Panel in the Viewport Toolbar"""
    bl_label = "Generate"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def draw(self, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        mode_string = context.mode
        edit_object = context.edit_object

        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.label(text="Generate objects:")

        if mode_string == 'OBJECT':
            layout.menu("INFO_MT_add", text="Add")
        elif mode_string == 'EDIT_MESH':
            layout.menu("INFO_MT_mesh_add", text="Add")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**code (the explicit way)**

Gives something like this:

[image]

```
import bpy

def execute_operator(self, context):
    eval('bpy.ops.' + self.primitive + '()')

class MyShortAddonProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    mode_options = [
        ("mesh.primitive_plane_add", "Plane", '', 'MESH_PLANE', 0),
        ("mesh.primitive_cube_add", "Cube", '', 'MESH_CUBE', 1),
        ("mesh.primitive_circle_add", "Circle", '', 'MESH_CIRCLE', 2),
        ("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add", "UV Sphere", '', 'MESH_UVSPHERE', 3),
        ("mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add", "Ico Sphere", '', 'MESH_ICOSPHERE', 4),
        ("mesh.primitive_cylinder_add", "Cylinder", '', 'MESH_CYLINDER', 5),
        ("mesh.primitive_cone_add", "Cone", '', 'MESH_CONE', 6),
        ("mesh.primitive_torus_add", "Torus", '', 'MESH_TORUS', 7)
    ]

    primitive = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=mode_options,
        description="offers....",
        default="mesh.primitive_plane_add",
        update=execute_operator
    )


class CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """A Custom Panel in the Viewport Toolbar"""
    bl_label = "Generate"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.label(text="Generate objects:")
        col.prop(context.scene.my_short_addon, "primitive")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_short_addon = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyShortAddonProperties)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_short_addon


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

You were close..   Do I need to explain what's going on here or do you think you can figure it out?

Comment: Sorry, thank for this script
so, when i click for example in mesh cube, Box appears as the following picture:
[IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/2vx3e3s.png[/IMG]
how to add this, knowing that I created a script that tied between number of cubes and dimensions

Comment: Now you are asking a separate question. Ask another new question. Personally I would simply hit `F6` directly after adding the primitive, that's the _Operator Properties_.  I'm not sure if it's possible to display those inside your addon's panel..  -- that wasn't part of your original question.

Comment: ok no problem, thank you again, I expected someone who can do that.

Comment: it might be possible but you should ask a new separate question if you want an answer

Comment: something like "is it possible to display the Operator properties of an Active Add Primitive operator in a Custom Panel"

Comment: for example the active operator : `bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].operators[-1].properties.segments = 10` , if you just added Primitve UV Sphere

Comment: not work this, each mesh has properties!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32865/discussion-between-saded-and-zeffii).